# $\log(x)$ or $\ln(x)$ to denote the natural logarithm in research papers?

Tags: soft-question, journals, research

Since the natural logarithm, i.e. with base $e$, is very commonly used in research papers and that both $\ln(x)$ and $\log(x)$ are used to denote it, it is natural* to ask which of these notations to use when preparing a paper. The fact that both are used in literature concerning the same topics  gives rise to unnecessary confusions and/or definitions. Both have their advantages and disadvantages:

- The notation $\ln(x)$ bears no ambiguity, as its name is the abbreviation of the French *logarithme naturel*, or natural logarithm. One does not need to *define* what it denotes, it is self-explanatory. However, not everyone likes to use it, because...
- The notation $\log(x)$ is used much more widely for historical  reasons as well as notational conventions. However, literally *every time* it is mentioned in a paper, it is followed by something along the lines of "*where $\log(x)$ denotes the natural logarithm, whose base value is $e$*", which is not only cumbersome for the reader (who has read this phrase a hundred times before), but can also be avoided by simply using $\ln(x)$.

So which notation is best suited for denoting $\log_e(x)$ and why?

---

*pun not intended

Comment: In either case it should be $\log$ instead of $log$ and $\ln$ instead of $ln$.

Comment: My 2 cents: $\log$ for base $e$, $\log_x$ for base $x \neq e$, and $\ln$ never, it is an abomination introduced by the manufacturers of pocket calculators.

Comment: @Dirk You are free to edit the question if you want

Comment: @J.J.Green That is exactly my point :) However, a lot of papers still use $ln$... I am not sure which is now the "correct" accepted convention

Comment: At least in some parts of computer science the default meaning of $\log$ is $\log_2.$ For example  comparison sorts can't do better then $\log{n!}\approx n\log n$ where  $n \log n$ means $n log_2 n.$ So it depends on your audience if you need to spend a sentence saying explicitly what base you intend.

Comment: There is an implicit convention to use trigraphs rather than digraphs to denote standard functions ($\exp$, $\cos$, $\tan$, $\log$, $\operatorname{det}$, $\lim$, $\sup$, $\operatorname{adj}$, $\operatorname{vol}$, etc.), except in those rare cases in which there is no obvious pronounceable trigraph available (e.g. $\operatorname{tr}$ for the trace, or $\operatorname{st}$ for the standard part of a nonstandard real).  Note these are all contractions rather than initialisms. 
 $\operatorname{ln}$ violates these conventions.

Comment: In the even rarer cases where initialisms would be used, the convention is to write them in capital letters (e.g. $\operatorname{BB}$ for the Busy Beaver function).  But one would then use $\operatorname{NL}$ instead of $\operatorname{ln}$, given that mathematics is mostly written in English these days rather than French.

Comment: One reason to prefer trigraphs over digraphs is that digraphs are far likelier to also occur by accident in one's mathematical expressions, for instance if one is manipulating two variables named $l$ and $n$ then there is some chance of forming the product $ln$ without intending this to be the logarithm.  It is far rarer to see three variables $l,o,g$ multiplied together to form $log$.

Comment: @J.J. Green: Regarding "*it is an abomination introduced by the manufacturers of pocket calculators*", $\ln$ was used as early as 1893 in Irving Stringham's book [**Uniplanar Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/uniplanaralgebra00stri) (see p. 41). You can also find $\ln$ used in Charles Smith's 1900 book [**Elementary Algebra for the Use of Schools and Colleges**](https://archive.org/details/elementaryalgeb05smitgoog) (see p. 437).

Comment: @TerryTao Those are excellent points, thank you.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz, of course one reason for the casualness about base in that context is that it's almost always $\mathrm O(\log n)$, not just $\log n$, that is of interest; and in that asymptotic context the base doesn't matter.

Comment: @LSpice That is true. However not always. A binary tree with $n$ leaves has height at least $\log n$ with equality for $n$ a power of two and the complete binary tree. There the intention is $\log_2$ although I've seen $\lg.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In number theory, the notation  $ \log $  is commonly used, especially when asymptotics are considered. One also frequently uses the notation  $ \log_{k} $ for the  $ k $ -th iterate of this function. Indeed the natural logarithm is essentially the only one that matters. This may not be true for other subfields of mathematics.

Comment: You're right for number theory (and complex analysis [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm), where it is log or Log).

Answer (score 1):

I would divide it into two cases:

1. If you care about the base being $e$, use $ln$ or state that $log$ is supposed to have base $e$.
2. If you only want a logarithm but don't care about which one, use $log$ (and maybe state that you don't care about the base). This case often arises when talking about growth of functions, running times of algorithms, etc, as logs with respect to different bases only differ by a constant.

In general, there is no "best solution" for your problem, otherwise there wouldn't be different versions running around. Make sure that your paper gets the message across, is correct and nice to read. If you do everything else right, using $ln$ or $log$ is then simply a question of style.

Comment: Yes, my question concerns exactly case 1: when one cares that the logarithm has base $e$ (i.e. the "natural" logarithm). The whole conundrum is whether to use $ln$, which is not widely used for this purpose currently, or $log$, in which case you *always* have to specifiy that it has base $e, which, as I stated is cumbersome and annoying.

Comment: Are you sure that $ln$ is not used even when we really want the base to be $e$? I would always go with $ln$ in this case, exactly to avoid this explanation problem, but that is only personal preference.